# Filtering object arrays based on uniqueValues

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I have an array of objects that needs to be filtered.
The object structure is like below:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Wheat',
        group: { name: 'Grains' }
    }, {
        name: 'Rice',
        group: { name: 'Grains' }
    }, {
        name: 'corn',
        group: { name: 'Grains' }
    }, {
        name: 'Oats',
        group: { name: 'Grains' }
    }, {
        name: 'Live Cattle',
        group: { name: 'Livestock/meat products' }
    }, {
        name: 'pork Bellies',
        group: { name: 'Livestock/meat products' }
    }
]
```

I need to have something like this in order to display it on GUI.
Separate out array based on their group name. Since Group names are going to be unique but each group can have multiple choices under it.

So I want to create a HashMap that has key as the Group name and Value as the Name.
the HashMap will look like below:

```
{
    'Grains':                  'Oats',
    'Grains':                  'Wheat',
    'Grains':                  'corn',
    'Livestock/meat products': 'Live Cattle',
    'Livestock/meat products': 'pork Bellies'
}
```

How can I achieve this using array functions or I need to have a separate logic to create a HashMap?

thanks,

Comment: you hash map can have only one key with the same name.

Comment: Your original structure is not a valid object. You can't have `group: name: "Grains"`, you need a value after each key.

Comment: Please update your post with the real JavaScript object structure. What you're showing isn't valid JS syntax.

Comment: Why isn't `Grains:Rice` in the desired result? What is the criteria for the filtering that removes it?

Comment: Did you mean something like `{groupname: "Grain", name: "Wheat"}`? It looks like the result is just `element.groupname + element.name`. Simply using these as keys in the `Map` will make them unique.

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the exact object and array structure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot produce a Map with duplicate keys. So you can replace the key and the value and then it will be possible, for example:

```
const
  data = [
      {
          name: 'Wheat',
          group: { name: 'Grains' }
      }, {
          name: 'Rice',
          group: { name: 'Grains' }
      }, {
          name: 'corn',
          group: { name: 'Grains' }
      }, {
          name: 'Oats',
          group: { name: 'Grains' }
      }, {
          name: 'Live Cattle',
          group: { name: 'Livestock/meat products' }
      }, {
          name: 'pork Bellies',
          group: { name: 'Livestock/meat products' }
      }
  ],
  result = data.map(({ name, group }) => [name, group.name]),
  resultAsMap = new Map(result);
```

Alternatively, you can create a set of strings, if it helps you, such as:

```
  result = new Set(data.map(({ name, group }) => `${group.name}: ${name}`));
```

You can also do "group by" which seems more appropriate for your case:

```
  reducer = (map, { name, group }) => map.set(group.name, (map.get(group.name) || []).concat(name)),
  result = data.reduce(reducer, new Map);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect way to do. Pass your data while calling this function.

```
function formatData(data) {
  const formattedData = {}
  data.forEach(({name, group}) => {
    formattedData[group.name] = formattedData[group.name] ? formattedData[group.name].concat(name) : [name];
  });
  return formattedData;
}
```